# Docusign unable to validate OAuth token

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I am new to using DocuSign and am trying to get a the authorization code as on this page: https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/authcode/authcode-get-token/.

I have constructed my code for this in C# as follows:

```
    var docuSignUri = "https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?"; // base path
    docuSignUri += "response_type=code"; //response type 
    docuSignUri += "&scope=signature"; //scopes
    docuSignUri += "&client_id=0b86bXXX-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXXXXXXXee55"; //integration key
    docuSignUri += "&redirect_uri=https://www.google.com"; //redirect uri

    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(docuSignUri);
    StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
    var responseData = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("docusign auth code:" + responseData);
```

I'm not getting a response anything like what the DocuSign documentation mentions though.  I get a long HTML page that has stuff like:
"Certificate cannot contain a private key"
and that I need to confirm company details.  I'm using the develop sandbox and the account-d url is correct for that?  Can anyone point me to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Nvm, I misread the documentation and all is good now.

Answer (score 0):

You do need to actually have an interactive user. You cannot just use a web request for Auth Code Grant. You need to open a browser and have a human log in.
If you need the ability to do this without a human (say a commandline  process), you may want to use JWT.